# problem ros_control

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1431969494.886616] Controller Spawner: Waiting for service /rbcar/controller_manager/load_controller
[WARN] [WallTime: 1431969525.172190] Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209445/problem-ros_control/) by [dagargme23](https://answers.ros.org/users/22397/dagargme23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-18**:
No one is going to help you like this; they can't. We don't know what OS, which version of ROS, version of `ros_control`, what you are trying to do, what you already have done, what failed nor what you tried to solve it yourself. Please update your question with the revelant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without further information (as the question comment states), all I can say is that you don't have a `controller_manager` running on the `rbcar/controller_manager` namespace. If a `controller_manager` is indeed running, it's not in `rbcar/controller_manager`, which is where the spawner script is being launched (and is expecting to find it).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0